# Non-singleton top component in Netbeans 8.0

Tags: java, netbeans, singleton, netbeans-platform

I'm trying to create a non-singleton Top Component for my Netbeans Platform project. There's a handy wizard for creating all types of files and components, including a singleton Top Component, but nothing for non-singleton ones, even though that would seem like a common use-case. What's going on there - am I missing something?

Anyway there's instructions for doing [a work-around](http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqNonSingletonTopComponents) to get what I want, but it only applies up to Netbeans version 6.9. I've tried it in a later version and the module refuses to load.

I'm using Netbeans 8.0. How can I make a non-singleton Top Component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to make a singleton top component then in the annotation @TopComponent.OpenActionRegistration I removed the preferredID.

Thanks to [Geertjan Wielenga](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/singleton_non_singleton_topcomponent_via) and [Aloys Mendoza](http://www.geektriathlete.com/2014/09/how-to-create-non-singleton-top.html?showComment=1410247443255#c6105625978621209150)

I'm still a bit nervous because this seems like a hack, exploiting unintended side effects of Netbeans code. So it might not work in a future version of Netbeans, but hopefully by then there will be a documented non-hacky way to do it.